# Noexcept variadic is_nothrow_constructible_v

Tags: c++, noexcept

Which of them is the correct one and why?

I think it's the first one because `Ts` already have the `&&` or `const &` associated with the type but I like to be sure and there really isn't that many examples of this particular case of `noexcept`.

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
    T test;

    // A
    template <typename... Ts>
    Test(Ts &&... ts) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Ts...>)
        : test(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {
    }

    // B
    template <typename... Ts>
    Test(Ts &&... ts) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Ts &&...>)
        : test(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer option C.  You can use the [`noexcept` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) in the noexcept specifier and have it evaluate the call for you.  I find this a lot easier to read an understand since you use the expression you want to do for exception specifier.  In you case that would look like

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
    T test;

    // C
    template <typename... Ts>
    Test(Ts &&... ts) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)))
        : test(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {
    }
};
```

And now the code says `Test(Ts &&... ts)` is noexcept if `T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)`is noexcept.

Comment: Ah, but then you must've forgot, you can also use the `noexcept` identifier inside the `noexcept` operator inside the `noexcept` specifier, like so : `noexcept(noexcept(noexcept(yesexcept)));`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken *noexception*?

Comment: @NathanOliver, but from the options I gave, which of them would give me the same result?

Comment: @JoãoPires I believe A is the correct way to do it since it will either be a `T` or `T&`.  Can't sayy 100% though so I didn't want to make it part of the answer.  That is why I like C best.  I don't have to think about what `Ts` is and how it will play with `decval`.